# How to handle ajax post method

Tags: jmeter

How to update response of a current page after sending the "ajax post method"?

I already parametrize the parameters which are needed in post body, but after sending it to the server , I couldn't see any changes to my Http sampler.

PS:This is the registration scenario.Parameters that are going on server are name, email, password etc. After sending it , page appears with congratulation and with email id.But in results , i couldn't find any email?